ASP.NET Core Web API component tests
I'm creating an extension to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity to support Entity-Based-Access-Control. I have several components, including custom middleware, authorization requirements, and base components/services like the custom model binder I posted in this answer.
Although I could unit test some of these components by providing the necessary metadata myself, it's much more convenient to just use them in the context of an API that provides this metadata.
Testing an existing API is rather simple, using one WebApplicationFactory and the Program or StartUp.
But in this case, I don't have an API, so I would have to create an API for the test cases. Would this still be the best approach? Also, one big API containing all the test cases may not be the best solution since I cannot test the components in isolation. Some of the components need database access, some don't. All calls would go through the custom middleware because I have to add it to test it.
I would test the custom model binder by just calling it in a controller endpoint and then comparing the result to the model provided by in the endpoint method parameter. But the middleware could intercept there.
So it may be better to create multiple separate APIs. But when having multiple controllers for different test cases and different APIs in the same project MapControllers would just map all controllers in all APIs although these APIs may not have to necessary services, ... So the next step would be to create a separate project for each API test group. But now the complexity of rather simple tests keeps increasing...
So how to test components that need the context of a Web API?
PS: would you still consider these tests integration tests? Or are they now E2E tests or any other type?
